# script to add files to SVN with filters

Tags: regex, svn, bash, scripting

My bash scripting is weak. I want to create a script that filters and add files to the svn.

So far i have this

```
ls | egrep -v "(\.tab\.|\.yy\.|\.o$|\.exe$|~$)"
```

I tried to output it using exec but couldnt figure out how. Before that I checked if svn add uses regex. I am not sure if it does and i couldnt figure out how to reverse the above without the -v (i tired `"[^((\.tab\.|\.yy\.|\.o$|\.exe$|~$))]"` but that didnt work as expected (it seems to only ignore .tab. files))

How do i create a script to add files to svn after applying a filter? Would this be the most simple way? -> use ls, grep, put into a bash array then use a foreach with an svn add $element ?

NOTE: This is using linux, i dont think i'll have this running on windows (i couldnt set up bison) so as long as it works on most linux distros i am happy. Ignore the fact the above uses .exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A number of ways:

1. Use backticks: `svn add` ``ls | egrep stuff
2. Use xargs: `ls | egrep stuff | xargs svn add`
3. Use find and xargs: `find . -type f -name *.c -print | grep -v '\.svn' | xargs svn add`

Obviously, change "stuff" and the "-name *.c" to suit your requirements...

Comment: xargs in the second method seems to choke on the newline-delimited output of ls. At least on my machine (Ubuntu 12.04).

Answer (score 1):

Try using find.

`find <pattern> -prune .svn -exec svn add {} \;`

The command following exec will be executed for each file and {} will be replaced with the filename at each iteration.

I'm not in front of my linux system so I can't get you a pattern that you need right now but if you read the man, you might get there.

Comment: if you (or anyone) can tell me how to ignore my .svn folder this would be the correct answer.

Comment: Haven't tested the above but to ignore the .svn folder, you'd use the -prune switch following (or perhaps before) your pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to this is to add those file extensions and the .svn folder to your SVN ignore pattern.

Armed with a client configured as such, you could then do `svn add *` and get only what you want into SVN.